# SQL Efficient way implementing not any of

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, many-to-many

Let suppose we have three tables, one for persons (person_id, person_name, street_name, ...), one for city districts (district_id, district_name, ...), and one for district-streets 1-N pairs (district_id, street_name). I want to select persons who DO NOT live in a specific district (identified by district_name) (T-SQL environment).

```
 SELECT P.Person_id
   FROM persons P
   JOIN Districts D on D.Name='1. district'
   JOIN Districts_Streets S on S.District_ID=D.District_ID
   WHERE ????
```

Comment: No join condition between p and d?

Comment: What is your metric for _efficient_? Fewest characters in the query? Minimizing I/O? ...

Comment: @HABO execution time is the key point.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't `<>` do what you want?

```
SELECT P.Person_id
FROM persons P JOIN
     Districts_Streets S 
     ON P.street_name = S.street_name JOIN
     Districts D 
     ON S.District_ID = D.District_ID
WHERE D.Name <> '1. district';
```

You do need to set up the joins correctly.

Comment: Another solution is:

  SELECT P.PersonID
    FROM Person P 
    LEFT JOIN 
       (  SELECT S.Street_Name FROM Districts_Streets S 
             INNER JOIN Districts D ON D.District_ID = S.District_ID
           WHERE D.Name<>'1. district') L
    ON L.Street_Name = P.Street_Name
  WHERE L.Street_Name IS NULL

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak . . . Why would you use a `LEFT JOIN` for such simple logic?